# perlin simplex worley noise libraries for tiling in javascript or HTML5 in general?

Tags: tiles, perlin-noise, simplex-noise

I am curious if there are libraries already developed for creating these noises in javascript?

I have searched the web for about two hours looking for libraries in javascripts. I have seen this implementation for the simplex noise:

https://gist.github.com/304522

but I have not seen any libraries made up specifically for javascript.

If no one knows of any libraries then link suggestions on how to develop these functions would be great as well. I am currently doing Google searches for everything I have asked here I just figured better to have multiple web crawlers helping me out concurrently :) Also if someone on stack overflow has already found a quality site then even better.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://carljohanrosen.com/processing/) you can find a thoroughly explanation of the algorithm, also the original code from Worley (explained in [Texturing and modelling. A procedural approach](http://books.google.com/books/about/Texturing_modeling.html?id=bDlSJd8GfMcC)) ported to Processing.

At the moment I'm working deploying to Javascript.

Comment: Here is the Javascript implementation of Worley noise: http://hellopixel.net/experiments/javascript/worley-noise/worley.html

Answer (score 1):

For the tiling part of your question: if you have a Perlin or Simplex noise function you don't really need a library to create tiling images because the math is really not that difficult. What is difficult is understanding how it works. For instance: a spherical noise map is way easier than simple 2D tiling image because you need to work with four dimensions for the latter.

I once wrote a blog post explaining in detail [how to create tiling noise](http://www.sjeiti.com/creating-tileable-noise-maps/) (including Javascript code examples).
It shows you how to tile in linear, cylindrical, planar and spherically (including cubical panorama).

Answer (score 0):

I've made a javascript app that renders perlin/simplex noise to an html5 canvas, you can find it here: http://lencinhaus.github.com/canvas-noise

Well it's not a proper library, but the javascript code contains implementations of value noise, perlin noise (both in classic and improved versions) and simplex noise, all derived from the original Perlin's C implementations (or a more optimized java version for simplex noise, see the references in the code). You can tweak the noise parameters visually and immediately see the results in the browser, so maybe it can be useful for you.

hope that helps!